# Installing Ruby 1.9.3 OSX 10.7.4 breaks after altering PATH

Tags: ruby, macos, shell, path

I was having trouble installing ruby 1.9.3-p194   from ruby 1.8.7 on my mac osx 10.7.4.

I have was trying to fix my homebrew after running "brew doctor" and got the message of "/usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths: c++-4.2
    cpp-4.2
    erb
    g++-4.2
    gcc-4.2
    gcov-4.2
    gem
    i686-apple-darwin11-cpp-4.2.1
    i686-apple-darwin11-g++-4.2.1
    i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1
    irb
    rake
    rdoc
    ri
    ruby
    testrb"

I fixed it by entering the following, which I found on another stackoverflow answer:

`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin$PATH"`

Lo and behold! when I typed that ruby updates to 1.9.3-p194. Ruby files seem to compile and run just fine.

However, afterward, my navigation around terminal is messed up severely. For instance I can't do the command "open example_file.html" and have the file pop up in Chrome, instead I get the error:
"-bash: open: command not found"

Also, when I change directory, I get an error, inputting "$ cd desktop" yields the output,
"-bash: dirname: command not found"

but the directory does then changes... strange.

When I exit out of a terminal window all this resets. I'm back to Ruby 1.8.7, have to use the PATH command again to update to 1.9.3, command line navigation gets broken again.

Any guidance on how to remedy so I can use 1.9.3-p194 and also have normal terminal navigation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paths are separated by colons. You're missing a colon before `$PATH` in your export. Due to this your previous paths won't get concatenated properly, making `open`, etc unavailable. The simple fix -

`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: That worked, thanks!

One slight issue though, every time I exit terminal, I have to redo this change, how can I make it permanent?

Comment: To make it permanent you should put this into the `.bash_profile` file in your home directory. If you use zsh, that'd be `.zshrc` file in the same place. Also, files beginning with a dot are usually hidden.